# This menu button doesn't work,

Tags: css

```
<title>Teste</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
</head>
<body>
<header>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
<div class="navbar-header">
<a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Teste</a>
<button  class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-target=".navbar-collapse"  data-toggle="collapse">Teste</button>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" >
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li><a href="#">1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">2</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
</header>
```

I'm new to CSS. I was following tutorial step by step, however the button still doesn't work, the rest of it, is perfect. I tried on http://www.bootply.com/ and it works fine, the menu drops down.

Comment: Can you explain more? what's not working ?

Comment: On button click, the menu should dropdown. The CSS im using is the bootstrap.min.css, from bootstrap site.

Comment: yes I see that, but where have you placed it? is it navigating to the right file?

Comment: yes , the css is working fine , just the button doesn't show the menu

Comment: Did you include bootstrap.js file?

Comment: Yes, still doesn't drop down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out what was wrong, in the step by step tutorial, they didn't link the javascript the right way, i did a little google and now its working just fine.
Thanks for all the comments.